# Multiple sites on django-cms

Tags: django, django-cms

I try to create 3 sites on a django-cms installation. I registered in the administration of django-cms 3 sites:

- cmsdjango
- site01
- site02

I go to correctly **cmsdjango**. But I get an error "**500 Internal Server Error**" when I try to access sites '**site01**' or '**site02**'. And in the apache error log :

```
[Wed Mar 05 08:30:53.238161 2014] [:error] [pid 3064] [remote 127.0.0.1:15543] mod_wsgi (pid=3064): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/oss974/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango/wsgi_site01.py'.
[Wed Mar 05 08:30:53.238242 2014] [:error] [pid 3064] [remote 127.0.0.1:15543] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Mar 05 08:30:53.238257 2014] [:error] [pid 3064] [remote 127.0.0.1:15543]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
[Wed Mar 05 08:30:53.238365 2014] [:error] [pid 3064] [remote 127.0.0.1:15543]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Wed Mar 05 08:30:53.238376 2014] [:error] [pid 3064] [remote 127.0.0.1:15543]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
[Wed Mar 05 08:30:53.238401 2014] [:error] [pid 3064] [remote 127.0.0.1:15543]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Wed Mar 05 08:30:53.238410 2014] [:error] [pid 3064] [remote 127.0.0.1:15543]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Wed Mar 05 08:30:53.238423 2014] [:error] [pid 3064] [remote 127.0.0.1:15543]     if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
[Wed Mar 05 08:30:53.238431 2014] [:error] [pid 3064] [remote 127.0.0.1:15543]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
[Wed Mar 05 08:30:53.238445 2014] [:error] [pid 3064] [remote 127.0.0.1:15543]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Wed Mar 05 08:30:53.238453 2014] [:error] [pid 3064] [remote 127.0.0.1:15543]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Wed Mar 05 08:30:53.238473 2014] [:error] [pid 3064] [remote 127.0.0.1:15543]     __import__(name)
[Wed Mar 05 08:30:53.238485 2014] [:error] [pid 3064] [remote 127.0.0.1:15543] ImportError: No module named site01_urls
```

Here is the configuration I used:

- Linux Mint 16
- Apache 2.4
- Python 2.7.5+
- django 1.5.5
- django_cms 2.4.3

**Project folder**

`/home/raphael/www/cmsdjango`

**Folder structure**

```
├── cmsdjango
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── site01_urls.py
│   ├── site02_urls.py
│   ├── media
│   ├── settings_site01.py
│   ├── settings_site02.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── template_1.html
│   │   └── template_2.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi_site01.py
│   ├── wsgi_site02.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
└── manage.py
```

**'settings' files**

*/home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango/settings.py* :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
gettext = lambda s: s
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'cmsdjango',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '', 
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
SECRET_KEY = '&vqh+-mqm9+3^yka2(m(p&n-rrqs#*@+ejh%g3*0qquhfmtpqd'
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'cmsdjango.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cmsdjango.wsgi.application'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "templates"),
)
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('template_1.html', 'Template One'),
    ('template_2.html', 'Template Two'),
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'cms',
    'mptt',
    'menus',
    'south',
    'sekizai',
    'cms.plugins.file',
    'cms.plugins.flash',
    'cms.plugins.googlemap',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    'cms.plugins.picture',
    # 'cms.plugins.snippet',
    'cms.plugins.teaser',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    'cms.plugins.video',
    'cms.plugins.twitter',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'cms.context_processors.media',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
)

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
]
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

/home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango/settings_site01.py :

```
from settings import *
SITE_ID = 2
ROOT_URLCONF = 'site01_urls'
DEBUG = False
```

/home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango/settings_site02.py :

```
from settings import *
SITE_ID = 3
ROOT_URLCONF = 'site02_urls'
DEBUG = False
```

**'urls' files**

*/home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango/urls.py* :

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

/home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango/site01_.py :

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

/home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango/site02_urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

**'wsgi' files**

*/home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango/wsgi.py* :

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cmsdjango.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

/home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango/wsgi_site01.py :

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cmsdjango.settings_site01")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

/home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango/wsgi_site02.py :

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cmsdjango.settings_site02")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**'hosts' file**

*/etc/hosts* :

```
...
127.0.0.1   cmsdjango
127.0.0.1   site01
127.0.0.1   site02
...
```

**''virtualhost' files**

*/etc/apache2/sites-available/cmsdjango.conf* :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cmsdjango
    ServerAlias cmsdjango
    DocumentRoot /home/raphael/www/cmsdjango
    <Directory /home/raphael/www/cmsdjango>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>    
    WSGIDaemonProcess cmsdjango processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/home/raphael/www/cmsdjango
    WSGIProcessGroup cmsdjango
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango/wsgi.py
    <Directory /home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango>
        Order allow,deny
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cmsdjango_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cmsdjango_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

*/etc/apache2/sites-available/site01.conf* :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site01
    ServerAlias site01
    DocumentRoot /home/raphael/www/cmsdjango
    <Directory /home/raphael/www/cmsdjango>
        <Files wsgi_site01.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>    
    WSGIDaemonProcess site01 processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/home/raphael/www/cmsdjango
    WSGIProcessGroup site01
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango/wsgi_site01.py
    <Directory /home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango>
        Order allow,deny
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cmsdjango_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cmsdjango_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

*/etc/apache2/sites-available/site02.conf* :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site02
    ServerAlias site02
    DocumentRoot /home/raphael/www/cmsdjango
    <Directory /home/raphael/www/cmsdjango>
        <Files wsgi_site02.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>    
    WSGIDaemonProcess site02 processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/home/raphael/www/cmsdjango
    WSGIProcessGroup site02
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango/wsgi_site02.py
    <Directory /home/raphael/www/cmsdjango/cmsdjango>
        Order allow,deny
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cmsdjango_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cmsdjango_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: shouldnt it be ROOT_URLCONF = 'cmsdjango.site01_urls' instead of ROOT_URLCONF = 'site01_urls'

Comment: I changed the files and settings_site01.py and settings_site02.py without result.

Comment: hmm. and does apache error now says: ImportError: No module named cmsdjango.site01_urls ?

Comment: Displays 'Server Error (500)' but no error in cmsdjango_error.log

Comment: ok so you are passed that error now. try to set DEBUG = True in site01 and site02 settings

Comment: site01 works great but not the site02. Something wrong maybe?

Comment: Thank you very much. Not easy to find information when you start python and django. Thank you again.